# Scene Builder shows previous items as yellows boxes which dont disappear

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using scene builder 8.
And the problem is dragging around items in the editor, the editor shows a yellow shadow to show a preview where the item will be. However, these yellow boxes do not disappear.

java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

OS

```
OS: Fedora 27 TwentySeven
```

Scene Builder

```
The latest version of Scene Builder for Java 8 is 8.4.1, it was released on Oct 17, 2017.
```

[Scene Builder Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Fsk.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: You may need to post info about `SceneBuilder`, your operation system, and your version of `Java`.

Comment: updated some info